# wear 2.0 sensors: Build an ecg with the body sensor at android wear 2.0 devices

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, android-sensors, heartbeat

Hallo Android developers,

i am creating an app to meassure datas with the Body sensor such like an ecg does. I am able to messure the heart rate. 
But I want to get the raw data in [mV] of the Body sensors. 
There are just TYPE_HEART_RATE and TYPE_HEART_BEAT to use.
Has anyone an solution to get the raw values over time?

It would be pretty fine if we can start a discussion about this Topic.

Comment: I don't know of any standard sensor that exports the raw data for HR.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Access Raw Sensor Data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors) that might be of help:

> The Sensors API lets you to read raw sensor data in your app in real
>   time. Use this API to:
>
> - List data sources available on the device and on companion devices.
> - Register listeners to receive raw sensor data.
> - Unregister listeners to stop receiving raw sensor data.
>
> The Sensors API does not automatically store sensor readings in the
>   fitness store, and sensor registrations created with the Sensors API
>   are not persisted when the system restarts. You typically use the
>   [Recording API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) to
>   record data in the background with persistent subscriptions, and you
>   use the Sensors API to display or process sensor readings in real
>   time. In many cases, you use both of these APIs in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot noogui. I will try this and give feedback if it works.